# How to tell python to check if two lists have the same degree?

Tags: python, list, polynomials

I need to tell Python to check if two lists have the same degree or not and I have no clue how to do it!

```
p_list = [1,0,1]
q_list = [4,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

list's don't generally have "degrees", they're just a "list of things"!  lists  do generally have a length, which can be accessed using the standard `len` function

if you happen to be treating some specific list as the coefficients of a polynomial then the degree might just the length of the list, e.g. `len(p_list)` would give you 3.

note: depending on how you're evaluating the polynomial (i.e. what the values in the list mean) it might make sense to return something other than the length, e.g. to filter out any high order zeros, but doing this depends on the order in which you store the coefficients.  say, if

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,0]
```

then `a` could be x³ + 2x² + 3x, or x + 2x² + 3x³, or even some other more esoteric encoding.  `b` would have a degree of 3 if you used the first encoding, and 2 in the second case